# Error during install cocoapods in BigSur, and unable to add cocoa pods

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

Mac OS: BigSur (11.6.1 (20G224))
Xcode Version: 13.2.1 (13C100)
Error shown in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this command
`sudo gem install cocoapods -v version —source http://rubygems.org`